# Mysql replace row if value = something

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to edit in 'videos' table, if 'category' column has the value set to 'Music' then replace it with the value '1'.

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to provide more information.. what is the table definition?  it seems like you're confusing rows with columns, and which value do you want replaced?

Comment: yes, i confused rows with columns. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. Is 'category' a column that is currently set to 'Music' for some row, and you want to set that to 1? If so:

```
update videos set category = 1 where category = 'Music'
```

Comment: yes, this was what i want to say. 'category' is a column, sorry  thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE videos
    SET category = '1'
    WHERE category = 'Music'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Answer (score 1):

err

```
update videos set category="1" where category="Music"
```

Take a look at the mysql docs, they are really good with explanations and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the category with '1'?

```
update videos
set
  category = '1'
where
  category = 'Music'
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the category your are referring to is a column, and not a row. If that is true then this solution is apt:

`UPDATE videos SET category = '1' WHERE category = 'Music'`

Go through the following link which contains tutorials, fruitful for beginners:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

With regards,

Jayesh